# Creating custom CDT refactorings without using internal classes

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, automated-refactoring

I'm trying to write a custom C++ refactoring using Eclipse Indigo and CDT 8.0.2. The CDT provides a class, `CRefactoring2`, which obtains the AST and provides hooks. But this class is in an internal package, so I assume it will change in future versions of Eclipse, and that I shouldn't subclass it.

Is there an external API (within the CDT; I don't particularly want to write all the AST-getting code from scratch) I can use to get ASTs and declare my own Eclipse CDT refactorings?

Comment: So what did you finally do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Jeff for sharing your method of obtaining the AST. I looked through my code and I have a different method of getting the AST but it also uses public API. I would like to post that method as well:

```
// Assume there is a variable, 'file', of type IFile
ICProject cProject = CoreModel.getDefault().create(file.getProject() );
ITranslationUnit unit = CoreModelUtil.findTranslationUnit(file);
if (unit == null) {
    unit = CoreModel.getDefault().createTranslationUnitFrom(cProject, file.getLocation() );
}
IASTTranslationUnit ast = null;
IIndex index = null;
try {
    index = CCorePlugin.getIndexManager().getIndex(cProject);
} catch (CoreException e) {
    ...
}

try {
    index.acquireReadLock();
    ast = unit.getAST(index, ITranslationUnit.AST_PARSE_INACTIVE_CODE);
    if (ast == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(file.getLocation().toPortableString() + ": not a valid C/C++ code file");
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    ...
} catch (CoreException e) {
    ...
} finally {
    index.releaseReadLock();
}
```

Mine is a little more involved; I basically kept changing things until stuff started working consistently 100% of the time. I have not any more to add on what you said about the actual refactoring.

Edit: To clarify: this is the safest way I have so far of getting the translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

For information on accessing and manipulating an AST, see [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-JavaCodeManipulation_AST/index.html) (Note that this code is written for Java. The CDT version of the ASTVisitor base class is found at `org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.ASTVisitor`).

The code we ended up writing to access a C++ AST from a file was essentially this:

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.CoreModel;
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.model.ITranslationUnit;
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.dom.ast.IASTTranslationUnit;

private IASTTranslationUnit getASTFromFile(IFile file) {
    ITranslationUnit tu = (ITranslationUnit) CoreModel.getDefault().create(file);
    return tu.getAST();
}
```

As for defining and registering a new refactoring, you'll want to look at [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Unleashing-the-Power-of-Refactoring/index.html).